# error when loading data into store in ember 1.0 using store.push function

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to manually load data into store. Here is the link to the jsBin http://jsbin.com/uYUsuTu/1/edit?html,output

My model is defined as :

```
    AS.AnalyticsRun = DS.Model.extend({
        'exerciseId': DS.attr('number'),
        'exerciseRunId': DS.attr('number'),
        'evolutionRunIds': DS.attr('string'),
        'analyticsTemplateId': DS.attr('number'),
        'analyticsPlan': DS.attr('string'),
        'commandScript': DS.attr('string'),
        'queued': DS.attr('boolean'),
        'final': DS.attr('boolean'),
        'createdBy': DS.attr('string'),
        'dateCreated': DS.attr('date'),
        'lastUpdatedBy': DS.attr('string'),
        'lastUpdated': DS.attr('date'),
        'analyticsRunParameters': DS.attr('string'),
        'evolutionRuns': DS.hasMany('evolutionRun')
    });
```

and I am trying to load data into store like:

```
var run = {"analyticsRun": [{"id": 2,
            "exerciseId": 1885,
            "exerciseRunId": 1938,
            "evolutionRunIds": null,
            "analyticsTemplateId": 13,
            "analyticsPlan": null,
            "commandScript": "test",
            "queued": false,
            "final": false,
            "createdBy": "Deewendra Shrestha",
            "dateCreated": "2013-10-04T13:40:23Z",
            "lastUpdatedBy": "Deewendra Shrestha",
            "lastUpdated": "2013-10-04T13:40:23Z",
            "analyticsRunParameters": null,
            "evolutionRuns": []}],
    "evolutionRuns": [
        {"id": 1378, "name": "aff_parameters_dannon.Pretest.Dannon_pman_KK2"},
        {"id": 1375, "name": "aff_parameters_dannon.Pretest.Dannon_pman_KM1"},
        {"id": 1377, "name": "aff_parameters_dannon.Pretest.Dannon_pman_KM2"},
        {"id": 1371, "name": "aff_parameters_dannon.Pretest.Dannon_pman_control"},
        {"id": 1376, "name": "aff_parameters_dannon.Pretest.Dannon_pman_KK1"}
    ]};
this.get('store').push('analyticsRun', run);
```

to which I get the error

**You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push`**

Not sure what I did wrong here!

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use:

```
this.get('store').pushPayload('analyticsRun', run);
```

Creating an object is not the same as pushing it...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got things working by using :

**this.get('store').createRecord('analyticsRun', run);**

instead.